# Standard deviation for a free path distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics, collision, statistics, mean-free-path

I would like to be able to describe a particles path before collisions with greater precision. We can calculate the "mean" free path of a particle before colliding moving particles, but I can't find anything about the standard deviation of these paths.

Being able to calculate the standard deviation would allow us to answer questions like "what is the chance a particle undergoes a collision in some time interval $t$" and the like.

Comment: _"what is the chance a particle undergoes a collision in some time interval t"_ This is given by $t$ in $e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}}$ where $\tau$ is the average _time_ between collisions. No statistics is necessary. You can see a derivation of this in most introductory thermodynamics texts. Similar in principle to derivation of the MFP. In fact, you can multiply $\tau$ by the average velocity to get the MFP.

Comment: @josephh due to the probability of a collision being proportional to the relative velocity between particles, at large times  the distribution is not poissonian: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.1291&ved=2ahUKEwjbw9Hope6EAxXqfKQEHZ9lD3QQFnoECBMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1Yz_VRa9nU6VUJwT05GRLb https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.2728